# open layers & typescript : Type error: Generic type 'MapBrowserEvent<EVENT>' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript, openlayers

trying to add an on click handler :
function OnMapClick(Event : MapBrowserEvent )

typescript complains with :
Type error: Generic type 'MapBrowserEvent' requires 1 type argument(s).

Can anyone help with this?
:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `MapBrowserEvent` is a generic type:

```
function OnMapClick(Event : MapBrowserEvent<UIEvent>)
```

Comment: thank you mmomtchev,

Can you please also share how you reached this solution ?
( how can I figure this out myself next time I encounter a similar problem?)

Comment: The error message is very explicit: `MapBrowserEvent` is a generic type and requires one type argument

Comment: I'll rephrase my question,
how did you know which type ("UIEvent")  needs to be supplied as a parameter?

Comment: Indeed, it is not documented anywhere. You can probably bug the Openlayers team to explicitly state it somewhere. The type is the type of the original browser event which happens to be `UIEvent`.